# Is it possible to remove status bar or disable close button on showModalDialog?

Tags: javascript

I am using `window.showModalDialog` to open a popup and wondering if there is any way to remove `x` in the top right-hand corner? or at least disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.showModalDialog` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog) for some time, and isn't even defined in Chrome. You might try building your own dialog box in html or using a plugin framework like jquery-ui or some such.

Comment: I cannot use jquery, has to be javascript

Comment: You could use window.open() and reference the other document with the window.opener property and access a form you built there or something. The popup has to be from the same domain for browser security reasons of course.